# No numeric types to aggregate?

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, aggregate, mean, numeric

I am trying to calculate the mean of different columns using groupby.
[Here is my code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuRbu.png)

However, as soon as I try to calculate mean, the error ['no numeric types to aggregate'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TScmc.png) appears. What is wrong with my code? Please help me!!! Thank you so much.

Comment: Post your code as text instead of image, so people can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

can you please post your code as text and some example data?
What are the contents of `data['low_stress']` and `data['high_stress']`?

My guess is, you use `pd.Series([low_stress])` and thereby instantiate a series of an array of your data. Using `pd.Series(low_stress)` will probably fix your problem.